# Associative Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, associativity

I have a non-empty set $R$ with a binary operation $*$. If the pair has an identity element $e\in R$ and 
$$(a*b)*(c*d)=(a*c)*(b*d)$$

holds for all $a,b,c,d \in R$, how do I then prove that this is associative?

I understand the concept that $x*(y * z) = (x * y)*z$, but I am unsure how to apply it here.

Comment: There are not that things you could try. How about trying to see what happens if one of those elements is the identity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $b=e$ it follows follows that $a\cdot b=a$ and $b\cdot d=d$ so that 
$$
(a\cdot b)\cdot(c\cdot d)=a\cdot (c\cdot d), \;  (a\cdot c)\cdot(b\cdot d)=(a\cdot c)\cdot d.
$$
Hence $a\cdot (c\cdot d)=(a\cdot c)\cdot d$ for all $a,c,d$, which means associativity.

Comment: I am taking this class as a final class for my Computer Science Degree. I have to graduate this summer, and the University put me in a situation where this Advanced Algebra class was the only option. I needed two prerequisites for the class, and I haven't taken either of them. I wish I understood how it is so easy to see that. How would I go one step further and prove that the pair (R, * ) is a semigroup with identity?

Comment: @TheCrownedPixel It's not easy; you have to get your hands dirty!  In this case, we are given only two assumptions: the existence of an identity, and a single equation.  Our first thought should be: What happens if we try combining these two assumptions?, i.e. What happens when we plug the identity into the given equation?

Comment: @Slade that makes sense now it is described to me. This as an online class has very limited explanation and examples to support the math. So if the identity and semigroup?