# A binary operation on $G$ satisfies $a\cdot(b\cdot c)=(a\cdot b)\cdot (a\cdot c)$ and has an identity, is it a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups, binary-operations, monoid

A binary operation on $G$ satisfies $a\cdot(b\cdot c)=(a\cdot b)\cdot (a\cdot c)$ and has an identity, is it associative? Is it a group?

I don't think it is associative but can't produce a convincing argument.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304427/associative-proof).

Comment: What is $G$? Is it itself a group?

Comment: @ Dietrich  Thank you for the help. But the question you referred to is more obvious than mine. Not quite sure how it helps. Any further guidance? thank you anyway.

Comment: @BernardMassé in this style problem, $G$ is clearly just a set that is endowed with a binary operation.  Any further properties about $G$, such as if it is commutative, associative, closed under inverse, etc... are unknown.

Comment: @ Bernard   G is a set. thanks!

Comment: Suppose $e$ is an identity.  Then we have $a = a\cdot e = a\cdot (e\cdot e) = (a\cdot e)\cdot (a\cdot e) = a\cdot a$.  If we were to suppose that $a$ has an inverse, then that would have implied that $a=e$ and so $G$ would be just the trivial group.  Now, if we were to assume that there exists some $a\neq e$, then inverses don't exist and that is where things can get interesting.

Comment: @ JMoravitz  Yep, I got a = a⋅a as well!

Comment: This looks funny to me.  Are you sure it's not $(a\cdot b)\cdot c = a\cdot (b\cdot c )$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi yes.  We are investigating the behavior of a set with a binary operation where the only thing about the binary operation we know for certain is that $a\cdot (b\cdot c) = (a\cdot b)\cdot (a\cdot c)$ and that there is an identity element.  We do not yet know whether or not $(a\cdot b)\cdot c = a\cdot (b\cdot c)$.  That is one of the things we are wanting to find out, and since $\cdot$ is not necessarily the usual multiplication, we cannot take that for granted and if it happens to be true it must be proven.

Comment: This looks like the distributive property which holds for the rings (used for relating additive&multiplicative operations) but defined on only 1 operation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $e$ denote the identity element.  Note that $$xy=x(ey)=(xe)(xy)=x(xy)$$ and $$xy=x(ye)=(xy)(xe)=(xy)x$$ for any $x,y\in G$.  Now we have $$a(bc)=(ab)(ac)=((ab)a)((ab)c)=(ab)((ab)c)=(ab)c,$$ proving associativity (the first two equalities are the given axiom, and the second two come from $(xy)x=xy$ and $x(xy)=xy$ for appropriate choices of $x$ and $y$).

However, $G$ does not have to be a group.  For instance, $G$ could be any totally ordered set with a greatest element, with the operation given by $ab=\min(a,b)$; this is not a group unless $G$ has only one element, since there are no inverses.  Or more generally, $G$ could be any partially ordered set in which any finite subset has a greatest lower bound, with $ab$ being the greatest lower bound of $a$ and $b$.  In fact, every commutative example is of this form (explicitly, you can define $a\leq b$ iff $ab=a$ and then $ab$ will be the greatest lower bound of $a$ and $b$ with respect to this order).

For an example that is not commutative, consider $G=\{e,a,b\}$ with the operation given by $xy=x$ unless $x=e$ in which case $xy=y$.

Comment: Hi, sorry. I can't see how (ac)=(ab)c here. Thank you for your answer by the way!

Comment: It's not true that $(ac)=(ab)c$ and I never used that...

Comment: Oh, maybe you are asking about $(ab)(ac)=((ab)a)((ab)c)$.  That's just $x(yz)=(xy)(xz)$ with $x=ab$, $y=a$, and $z=c$.

Comment: yes! thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

If it is a gruop, then it must be trivial:
Infact if you fix $a\in G$ then for each $b,c$ you have that

$a(bc)=(ab)(ac)$

but the operation is associative, so

$(ab)c=a(bc)=(ab)(ac)$

For $b=1,c=1$ you have

$a=a^2$

But $G$ is a group, so

$a=a^2a^{-1}=aa^{-1}=1$

Thus

$G=\{1\}$

Comment: This does the case for showing that if $G$ is a group *then* $G$ is trivial.  There is still the question of whether or not $G$ might not be a group in the first place.

Comment: This does not answer the question since you assume that $G$ is group.

Comment: @Jan It does answer the question: if $G$ has more than one element, then the operation cannot make $G$ into a group by Federico Fallucca's argument. If $G$ *does* have one element, then the operation does make $G$ into a group.

Comment: @RyleeLyman: Right, but you still have to show it is possible for $G$ to have more than one element.

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm confused. The statement of the question assumes that we are handed a set $G$ with a binary operation.

Comment: @RyleeLyman Up to the point it is shown that if $G$ is not trivial, then $G$ is not a group. The question is whether it is possible that $G$ is not trivial. For a complete answer one has to discuss whether $G$ could have at least two elements.

Comment: @RyleeLyman Thanks you for the answer, the idea is exactly what you said.

Comment: @Jan: Like others, I am mistified by the comment. This proof shows "If $G$ has more than one element, then it is not a group." Given the set and binary operation satisfying the property you have but two choices: (i) the set has exactly one element, and the operation is necessarily $x\cdot x = x$. Then it is a group. (ii) The set has either no elements or at least two elements; if it is empty it's not a group, because groups cannot be empty. If it has at least two elements, then this shows it is not a group. (cont)

Comment: @Jan: So, what exactly is your point? Are you saying that in order to answer the question one should also show that it is possible to have a set with more than one element and a binary operation that satisfies the given condition (even though it won't be a group)? I don't think that's true. Now, it *is* the case that there is another question that has not been answered: whether a set and an operation satisfying this property must be associative or not. But then that is not what you said.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: (Part of) the question is whether a set with an operation satisfying the given property _must_ be a group.  If there is an example with more than one element, then the answer to that question is no, and if there is no such example, the answer is yes.  So the question has not been answered completely unless you know whether such an example exists.

Comment: @EricWofsey: I don't see that reading, but I guess it's the spice of life and all.

Answer (score 2):

@JMoravitz already showed we can't get a non-trivial group this way, but also that $\cdot$ is idempotent. Associative non-group options include taking $\cdot$ to be $\land$ or $\lor$ on propositions, or similarly $\cap$ or $\cup$ on sets. The respective identities are True, False, the universe or $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

In this group, it is always true that

$$a\cdot(b \cdot c) = (a \cdot b) \cdot (a \cdot c)$$

for $a, b, c \in G$. Well, then this rule must be also valid for the case $a = b = c$ where $\forall a \in G$:

$$a^3 = a^4.$$

If we assume $(G, \cdot)$ is indeed a group, then it must also have inverses for any given element. So we can derive that,

$$a = e.$$

So this group must only consist of the identity if it exists. In this case associativity and existence of inverses will automatically follow. Hence,

$$G = \lbrace e \rbrace.$$

We have a trivial Abelian group of degree 1 here :)

Comment: Writing $a^3$ and $a^4$ could be questionable if the operation is not associative.

Comment: True. Then we should just assume $b, c = e$ as the Federico did.

Comment: Actually not true since i assume $(G, \cdot)$ is a group there. Hence i also assume associativity holds. @GEdgar